# CSS - background image not showing

Tags: html, css

I have rather unusual problem. It is hard to explain, so this is [address](http://010.rs/mali_oglasi) where you can take a look (web site is still in development, don't bother with PHP errors).

Problem is following - sidebar menu (with icons, on the right, below **Kategorije**) is dynamically created and each **li** have span tag made for icons (used as background image). This is working, except for the first one (**aksesoari**). And this one is also working, but only 50% of the time - when it is in hover state it is working. I tried everything, but it the internet gremlins are messing around with me. Can someone see where is the problem (problem is acquiring in all browsers)?

This is CSS code for that part (sidebar menu):

```
span[role=kategorija]{width: 24px;height: 24px; display: inline-block;position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -30px}

.kategorija_aksesoari {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0 0px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_aksesoari {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0 -24px}
.kategorija_auto_moto{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -29px 0px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_auto_moto {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -29px -24px}
.kategorija_casopisi{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -58px 0px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_casopisi {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -58px -24px}
.kategorija_filatelija{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -87px 0px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_filatelija {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -87px -24px}
.kategorija_knjige{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -116px 0px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_knjige {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -116px -24px}
.kategorija_kolekcionarstvo{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0px -53px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_kolekcionarstvo {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0px -77px}
.kategorija_masine_alati{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -28px -53px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_masine_alati {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -28px -77px}
.kategorija_muzika_filmovi{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -57px -53px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_muzika_filmovi {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -57px -77px}
.kategorija_numizmatika{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -87px -53px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_numizmatika {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -87px -77px}
.kategorija_ostalo{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -116px -53px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_ostalo {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -116px -77px}
.kategorija_racunari_oprema{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0px -106px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_racunari_oprema {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0px -130px}
.kategorija_sportska_oprema{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -29px -106px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_sportska_oprema {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -29px -130px}
.kategorija_tehnika{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -58px -106px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_tehnika {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -58px -130px}
.kategorija_telefoni{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -86px -106px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_telefoni {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -86px -130px}
.kategorija_kuca_dvoriste{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -116px -106px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_kuca_dvoriste {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -116px -130px}
.kategorija_nekretnine{background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -145px 0px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_nekretnine {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat -145px -24px}
```

Comment: Man - they all use the same friggen background image, assign them all a common class and reference the URL *once* in your CSS.  I think you have some reading up to do on CSS, no offense.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your HTML, and edit your CSS here down to only the parts that are necessary to demonstrate the problem - the link to your site is not useful because eventually it will change, crippling this question.

Comment: Also, what @Madbreaks said. You're ignoring the "C" in CSS.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your CSS link: `<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://010.rs/public/css/mali_oglasi.css">`. Try removing the space before the `http`.

Comment: @Madbreaks To be honest, I am so irritated by this problem that I didn't saw that (this is inherit code, it is not mine). BryanH this is the final version, no further changes will be made in the near future, but once I solve the problem I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not, as suggested by others, that you need to apply the background image to the non-hover state...this has already been done.

The clue here is that the declaration for the non-hover state is the **first** in the list of the background images. If you change the order of them, by putting the hover state first, the non-hover state is shown and the hover state doesn't work.

This must mean that the issue is further up in the CSS.

Having a look at the actual CSS, you will see:

```
.mali_oglas_izmena_selektovano {margin: 10px 0}
.mali_oglas_izmena_selektovano a {margin-right: 10px }

/
/* MALI OGLASI KATEGORIJE */

.kategorija_aksesoari {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0 0px}
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_aksesoari {background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0 -24px}
```

Note the `/` before the `/* MALI OGLASI KATEGORIJE */` comment? Remove this. It's causing the next CSS declaration to fail...which happens to be the non-hover state.

P.S. Just to clarify how I worked this out - I used [Google Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to view the source and play with the CSS file, on my client. It allows you to do wonderful things, like test changes in CSS and javascript without having access to the actual source.

Comment: This a life saving solution :). I am using Firebug, but I guess I was tring to find something big and complicate, when in fact solution was very simple :D. Than you for your help, it means a lot for my sanity :)

Comment: @Sasha no problems, it had me stumped for a bit...glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is two-fold:

1. Your CSS is a mess and is making it very difficult for you to debug, understandably
2. Your CSS only applies the background image for the `li` `span` on hover:

```
.kategorija_izbor li a:hover .kategorija_aksesoari {
    background: url('../img/resursi/kategorija/crne/icons.png') no-repeat 0 -24px;
}
```

I'd suggest fixing both.  ;)

Cheers

Comment: This is not my code, and I was so occupate with problem that I didn't notice it needs to optimization.

Comment: @j08691 - Thanks! How'd you whip it into shape?

Comment: @Sasha Point #2 is your problem.  You need to apply the background image to the non-hover state of the `<a>` tag as well.

Comment: I tried that, it is refusing to work no mater what I try. All other categories are working fine, and they use same code format as the first one.